# Disable hyperlinks in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, awt, jeditorpane, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane with HTML contents. Without changing the content type or calling setText, I would like disable the hyperlinks. I want

- The hyperlinks to have the same style as the surrounding text (usually meaning no underline or blue color)
- The mouse to not turn into a hand when I move it over hyperlinks

What is the easiest way to do this? I already know how to change the hyperlink listener, but now want the links to appear as normal text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define desired style for your "a" tag.
E.g. to set forn bigger use

```
((HTMLDocument)textPane.getDocument()).getStyleSheet().addRule("a {font-size:48px;}");
```

Comment: that's good, but how do I get rid of the hand that appears when I hover over it?

Comment: Er, set it to true. I meant true. Call setEditable(true) to disable hyperlinks.